# convert json to c# list of objects

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

Json string:

```
{"movies":[{"id":"1","title":"Sherlock"},{"id":"2","title":"The Matrix"}]}
```

C# class:

```
public class Movie {
  public string title { get; set; }
}
```

C# converting json to c# list of Movie's:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Movie> movies = jss.Deserialize<List<Movie>>(jsonString);
```

My `movies` variable is ending up being an empty list with count = 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps you should name first json node as `Movie` so it corresponds to the `Movie` class?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your c# class mapping doesn't match with json structure.

**Solution :**

```
class MovieCollection {
        public IEnumerable<Movie> movies { get; set; }
}

class Movie {
        public string title { get; set; }
}

class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                string jsonString = @"{""movies"":[{""id"":""1"",""title"":""Sherlock""},{""id"":""2"",""title"":""The Matrix""}]}";
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                MovieCollection collection = serializer.Deserialize<MovieCollection>(jsonString);
        }
}
```

Comment: I used this, it says: "the collection class (MovieCollection) is not supported for deserialization of an array. please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the C# structure, you can change the JSON string like this:

```
{[{"id":"1","title":"Sherlock"},{"id":"2","title":"The Matrix"}]}
```