# Server paging in kendo grid in web forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to load a kendo grid data from an aspx page. I am unable to perform serverpaging. I tried setting serverpaging : true. But still it is taking a lot of time to load grid.

Data from aspx page is retrieved via: Response.Write(JSON_result);

Grid in aspx page is declared as:

```
  var grid = $("#gridAllRuns").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: url_load,
                                dataType: "json"
                            },

                        },
                        pageSize: 100,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverSorting: true,
                        serverFiltering: true
                    },
                    height: $(document).height() - 250,
                    groupable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    reorderable: true,
                    //selectable: "multiple",
                    resizable: true,
                    // serverPaging: true,
                   // dataBound: resizeGrid,
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: [100, 500, 1000],
                        pageSize: 1000,
                        buttonCount: 10
                    },
                    // toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                    filterable: {
                        extra: false,

                        operators: {
                            string: {
                                eq: "equal to",
                                startswith: "starts with",
                                neq: "not equal to"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                    columns: [
                        {
                            title: "Name",
                            field: "FName",

                            width: 100,
                            filterable: true
                        },
                        {.......}] });
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you limiting count of records in `JSON_result` writing with `Response.Write(JSON_result);` to _take_ and _skip_ count sent by kendo?

Comment: No...am returning the total records..

Comment: You should limit it to _take_ and _skip_ parameters in serverside.

Comment: suppose if there are 20000 rows and I skip 15000 and get only 5000 rows, how can I get the remaining 15000 rows?

Comment: If you have 15000 records and your grid's datasource pagesize is 100 it means your grid has 15 (1500/100=15) pages. Everytime you change page the skip and skip calculated and sent to server to get the 100 records of that page.

Comment: Can I please get an example....because, here am dealing with three web servcies which are merged to form a single JSON object and this JSON object is what am sending from aspx page i.e response.write(JSON).

Comment: You should convert `JSON_result` to C# List<> check this:[convert json to c# list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254887/convert-json-to-c-sharp-list-of-objects). Then using Linq2Object limit your list<> to take and skip sent by kendo to your service. I'm busy these days sorry I can't give an exact code. But I try to write an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: And please put here code of aspx page which kendoGrid retrieved data from it. I mean the method which at the end of it you `Response.Write(JSON_result);`.

Comment: VenAddress = New Uri("getdata/ven")
VenData = instance.DownloadString(VenAddress)        
TreAddress = New Uri("/getdata/tre/" & curr_date)
TreData = instance.DownloadString(TreAddress)
Dim vndrData As List(Of VenClass) = serializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of VenClass))(VenData)
       Dim skip As Integer = If(_req("skip") = Nothing, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_req("skip")))
        Dim take As Integer = If(_req("take") = Nothing, 1000, Convert.ToInt32(_req("take")))

Comment: and am converting them to lists and using LINQ to combine all three web services into one and then loading into Grid

Comment: please edit your question and move the codes in comment to your question, it is really hard to read them. don't forget put the method definition too not just it's inner codes.