# How to Convert this json string to a real List Object

Tags: c#, json, object

Hey so this is my JSON string
[image: JSON Pic]

I want to convert the whole thing into an object and then search the first follower in the follows array.

Thanks for the help if I get some.

Second problem below thanks :)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.  It leads to an entropy death of the Universe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert json to c# list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254887/convert-json-to-c-sharp-list-of-objects)

Comment: Duplicate of [Easiest way to parse JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34043384/993547).

Comment: Not really :) Sorry

Answer (score 0):

run the scripts in Package Manager Console :

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

after that use this syntax :

```
List<type> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<type>>(json string)
```

Comment: Do I have to create the type for myself?

Comment: @Juri.B the type refer to your sample datetype that you want to convert json to it.

Comment: I don't have a sample datetype atm so I have to create it right?

Comment: yeah , and it must match with your json object.

Comment: @ParsaKarami Any reason to use `Newtonsoft.Json` over .net's own [`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Juri.B support async and await for operation and prepare some facilities